# Photo grid in specific order and alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAvmK.png

As you can see, each element is a square. #1 is larger than the others (400x400), while the others are 200x200 with a 2 pixel space between each square.

How can I recreate this in this specific order, and so that the squares that don't fit within the container are hidden off screen?

Here's the JSFiddle I started, but it lacks order:

https://jsfiddle.net/ugsquz01/5/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

li:first-of-type {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [CSS Flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)?

The code would go as follows:

HTML:

```css
.image-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 440px; /* to account for 404px wide first child and a possible scrollbar */
  width: 700px;
  overflow-x: scroll; /* change value to hidden to remove scrollbar */
}

.image-grid .image-grid-item:first-child {
  width: 404px;
  height: 404px; /* to account for 2px margins */
}

.image-grid .image-grid-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Flex</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image-grid">
    <div class="image-grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="image-grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="image-grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="image-grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="image-grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="image-grid-item">6</div>
    <div class="image-grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="image-grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="image-grid-item">9</div>
    <div class="image-grid-item">10</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Watch out for browser supports when using CSS Flexboxes. There should be javascript libraries that act like 'polyfills' for older browsers.

### A solution that doesn't use Flex Boxes

```css
.scrollable-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto; /* change value to hidden to remove scrollbar */
 width: 700px;
}
.scrollable-wrapper > * {
 float: left;
}
.image-grid {
 column-width: 204px;
 column-gap: 0;
  height: 440px; /* to account for 404px wide first child and a possible scrollbar */
}
.image-grid-item.first {
  width: 404px;
  height: 404px; /* to account for 2px margins */
}

.image-grid-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Flex</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="scrollable-wrapper">
      <div class="image-grid-item first">1</div>
      <div class="image-grid">
            <div class="image-grid-item">2</div>
            <div class="image-grid-item">3</div>
            <div class="image-grid-item">4</div>
            <div class="image-grid-item">5</div>
            <div class="image-grid-item">6</div>
            <div class="image-grid-item">7</div>
            <div class="image-grid-item">8</div>
            <div class="image-grid-item">9</div>
            <div class="image-grid-item">10</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer avoiding using flexbox for the browser support reason. I don't want to have to add JS to make sure it's compatible across all browsers. :/

Comment: It has pretty much full browser support. Unless you're targeting IE8 or something you should be fine. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.

Comment: Browser  support for multiple columns: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn, note that all the issues are with breaks which aren't used in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.. you can fancy it up later..

Expand the html area screen to see the results.

https://jsfiddle.net/gc1hby6v/

```
<ul>
  <li class="bigFull">1</li>
  <div class="club">
    <li class="smallHalf">2</li>
    <li class="smallHalf">3</li>
  </div>
<div class="club">
    <li class="smallHalf">4</li>
    <li class="smallHalf">5</li>
  </div>
  <div class="club">
    <li class="smallHalf">6</li>
    <li class="smallHalf">7</li>
  </div>
  <div class="club">
    <li class="smallHalf">8</li>
    <li class="smallHalf">9</li>
  </div>
</ul>


ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bigFull {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  line-height: 400px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin:2px;
}

.club{
  float:left;
}


.smallHalf {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin:1px;
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking he's looking for a solution where all the 10 objects are children of the same parent. Otherwise, he might as well use a table too.

Answer (score 0):

for later browser, flex(official) indeed  :

different approach:

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 404px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 1px 1px;/* BTW height + margins is more than 400px tall together ....*/
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px;/* fun for demo */
}

li:first-of-type {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  line-height: 400px;
  margin:1px
}

li:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 100%;/* push & squeeze them all to the left */
}
html {background:#333;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

---

To try to include IE10, you may test multiple column ***(still a draft candidate)*** but it  needs to be tricked to fake a first col twice wider and an extra wrapper to apply overflow. Snippet for demo only

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  float: left;
  column-width: 200px;
  column-gap: 1px;
  position: relative;
  height: 404px;
  padding-left: 401px;
}

li {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 1px 1px;/*BTW height + margins all together are over 400px tall ...*/
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px;/* fun demo*/
}

li:first-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  line-height: 400px;
  margin:1px;
}


.overflow {
overflow:hidden;
}
html {background:#333;color:gold}
```

```html
<p>multiple column - CSS3 - I do not advise to use.</p>
<div class="overflow">
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
</div>
```